# Email fallback solution

Tags: email, html-email, markup, fallback

Im making a email template and they wanna put background images underneath the text - and to most email clients that is a no no.
So i tough can you make a fallback to the clients that don't support it?
Or is their a hack to make it work?

[image]

On this picture you got a list over css support

also see **[this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)** link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a technique that is supported by all major clients: [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/). The VML is a hack for Outlook which doesn't support CSS background images (except in the [body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239098/automatically-resizing-a-vml-background-image-in-outlook/17242638#17242638)).

You should always set a `bgcolor` however as most clients load with images disabled.